# Rails project, while testing with capybara: ArgumentError: Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery : [4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Test that the form has 4 inputs is not working, I am copy pasting the line from the documentation:

```
assert_select "form input", 4
```

any ideas?

```
require "application_system_test_case"

class QuestionsTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test "visiting /ask renders the form" do
    visit ask_url

    assert_selector "p", text: "Ask your coach anything"

    assert_select "form input", 4
  end
end
```

The complete error message is:

```
Error:
QuestionsTest#test_visiting_/ask_renders_the_form:
ArgumentError: Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery : [4]
    test/system/questions_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:QuestionsTest>'
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Don't know why my question is wrong according to stackoverflow, after having read their guidelines.

Comment: It's the second time that my questions are evaluated with a -1. Could the admin please tell me what I am doing wrong so that I don't do same mistakes again and again? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `assert_select` method you're copying from documentation is a Rails method that was moved out of Rails into the `rails-dom-testing` gem around Rails 4.2.  However, the `assert_select` method you're actually calling is a Capybara provided method - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Minitest/Assertions#assert_select-instance_method - which deals with <select> elements, doesn't take the same parameters, and isn't the correct method for what you are trying to do. With Capybara what you are trying to do is

```
assert_css "form input", count: 4
```

which is the same as `assert_selector :css, "form input", count: 4`, which can also be written `assert_selector "form input", count: 4` if `Capybara.default_selector == :css`.